# Sorting an ObservableCollection<Object> Items?

Tags: c#, sorting, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection<Object> Items` The Object that is loaded into the viewmodel has `Car` and `CarGroups`.The Items collection is bound to the view via Binding and the grid is displaying the data in the collection. How can I sort the data ascending by the `Car` names? If anything changes then display the data on the `Car` Names ascending.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37208/sort-observablecollection-after-added-new-item

Comment: Perhaps make it an observable collection of IComparable?